# Merge pandas dataframe where columns don't match

Tags: python, pandas

I have different data in two dataframes. Both have two columns called `Date` and data corresponding to those date. However both the dates are of different frequencies.

`Dataframe1` contains data at the end of month. So there is only one entry for every month. `Dataframe2` contains dates which are not separated evenly. That is it may contain multiple dates from same month. For example if `Dataframe1` contains 30 Apr 2014,  `Dataframe2` may contain 01 May 2014, 07 May 2014 and 22 May 2014.

I want to merge the data frames in a way so that data from `Dataframe1` corresponding to 30 Apr 2014 appears against all dates in May 2014 in `Dataframe2`. Is there any simple way to do it?

Comment: What things have you tried?  Do you have some example code?  Could you add an example `dataframe` assignment that we can play with?

Comment: So is the date in df1 always 1 entry per month which corresponds to the following month in df2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be to add a month column for `df1` that is the current month + 1 (you'll need to roll December over to January which just means substituting 13 for 1). Then I'd set the index of df1 to this 'month' column and call `map` on df2 against the month of the 'date' column, this will perform a lookup and assign the 'val' value:

```
In [70]:
# create df1
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':[dt.datetime(2014,4,30), dt.datetime(2014,5,31)], 'val':[12,3]})
df1
Out[70]:
        date  val
0 2014-04-30   12
1 2014-05-31    3
In [74]:
# create df2
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['01 May 2014', '07 May 2014', '22 May 2014', '23 Jun 2014']})
df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'], format='%d %b %Y')
df2
Out[74]:
        date
0 2014-05-01
1 2014-05-07
2 2014-05-22
3 2014-06-23
In [75]:
# add month column, you'll need to replace 13 with 1 for December
df1['month'] = df1['date'].dt.month+1
df1['month'].replace(13,1)
df1
Out[75]:
        date  val  month
0 2014-04-30   12      5
1 2014-05-31    3      6

In [76]:
# now call map on the month attribute and pass df1 with the index set to month
df2['val'] = df2['date'].dt.month.map(df1.set_index('month')['val'])
df2
Out[76]:
        date  val
0 2014-05-01   12
1 2014-05-07   12
2 2014-05-22   12
3 2014-06-23    3
```